# When clicking the button to call the "hideProductIncentives" nothing is happening

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

The main issue I am facing here is that I have two divs and two directives that are nearly identical. The main difference between the two is that in one, most of the variables were changed to product, the other is global because I will need to make a lot of cosmetic changes down the road.

The global directive and HTML works exactly as expected. When clicking the "Close" button in that div, everything changes to "display:none", and when clicking the "Close" button in the productIncent div, the hideProductIncentives() function appears to not even be called.

Are the controllers and directives interfering with each other?

```
angular.module('ProductSelectorApp-main')
.directive('getGlobalIncentives', function (myFactory, serverData, $rootScope) {  
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" ng-click="showGlobalIncentives()">Incentives</button>',
        controller: function ($scope, $modal) {
          // $scope.selectedCurrency=[{ConversionRate:1.0 ,IsoCode:"USD" }]; 
           $scope.showGlobalIncentives = function() {
           document.getElementById('globalIncent').style.display='block';
           $scope.isRequestProcessing = false;



        }
        $scope.hideGlobalIncentives = function() {
            document.getElementById('globalIncent').style.display='none';
            $scope.isRequestProcessing = false;



         }      


        }
    }
});

angular.module('ProductSelectorApp-main')
.directive('getProductIncentives', function (myFactory, serverData, $rootScope) {  
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" ng-click="showProductIncentives()">Incentives</button>',
        controller: function ($scope, $modal) {
            this.name='testController';
          // $scope.selectedCurrency=[{ConversionRate:1.0 ,IsoCode:"USD" }]; 
           $scope.showProductIncentives = function() {
           document.getElementById('productIncent').style.display='block';
           $scope.isRequestProcessing = false;



        }

        $scope.hideProductIncentives = function() {
            document.getElementById('productIncent').innerHTML='';
            $scope.isRequestProcessing = false;



         } 

        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="globalIncent" class="white_content">
    **<button class="astext" style="float:right;" ng-click="hideGlobalIncentives()">Close</button>**    
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        <div class="slds-truncate" >Product Name</div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >PBP: </div></td>
        <td>


        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >RCP</div></td>
        <td>


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >RCP with Incentives: </div></td>
        <td>


        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >Net Price: </div></td>
        <td>


        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>


    <div class="slds-border_bottom" style="padding:5px;"></div>
    <div class="slds-checkbox" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;"> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="CheckUnCheckAll" value="Check" checked="" /> 
                <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="CheckUnCheckAll"> 
                  <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                  <span class="slds-form-element__label">Check/ UnCheck All</span> 
                </label> 
    </div> 
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Incentive</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                    <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Annual Price Increase" value="Annual Price Increase" checked="" /> 
                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Annual Price Increase"> 
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Annual Price Increase</span> 
                            </label> 
                      </div> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                  <option>%</option>
                                  <option>$</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                      </div>


                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                    <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Fund" value="Fund" checked="" /> 
                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Fund"> 
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Fund</span> 
                            </label> 
                      </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                  <option>%</option>
                                  <option>$</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                      </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                    <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Multi-Category" value="Multi-Category" checked="" /> 
                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Multi-Category"> 
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                            <span class="slds-form-element__label">Multi-Category</span> 
                            </label> 
                    </div> 
                </td>
                <td>
                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                  <option>%</option>
                                  <option>$</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                      </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                    <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Multi Channel" value="Multi Channel" checked="" /> 
                        <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Multi Channel"> 
                        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Multi Channel</span> 
                        </label> 
                    </div> 
                </td>
                <td>
                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                  <option>%</option>
                                  <option>$</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                      </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                    <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Total Category" value="Total Category" checked="" /> 
                        <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Total Category"> 
                        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                        <span class="slds-form-element__label">Total Category</span> 
                        </label> 
                      </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                  <option>%</option>
                                  <option>$</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                      </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                          <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Value Add" value="Value Add" checked="" /> 
                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Value Add"> 
                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Value Add</span> 
                            </label> 
                          </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                    <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                      <option>%</option>
                                      <option>$</option>
                                    </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                            <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                          </div>

                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                          <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Global Additioanl Incentive" value="Additional Incentive" checked="" /> 
                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Global Additioanl Incentive"> 
                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Additional Incentive</span> 
                            </label> 
                          </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                    <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                      <option>%</option>
                                      <option>$</option>
                                    </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                            <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                          </div>

                    </td>
            </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="slds-border_bottom" style="padding:5px;"></div>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div style="display:block">
        <div class="slds-truncate" style="float:left; font-weight:bold;">Overall Incentives % </div>

    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                    <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                  </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">
        <div style="float:right;padding:5px;">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;padding:5px;">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Apply</button>
        </div>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>        
</div>

            <!-- PRODUCT INCENTIVE DIV-->


            <div id="productIncent" class="white_content" ng-controller="testController">
                    **<button class="astext" style="float:right;" ng-click="hideProductIncentives()" >Close</button>**  
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" >Product Name</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >PBP: </div></td>
                        <td>


                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >RCP</div></td>
                        <td>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >RCP with Incentives: </div></td>
                        <td>


                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;"><div class="slds-truncate" >Net Price: </div></td>
                        <td>


                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>


                    <div class="slds-border_bottom" style="padding:5px;"></div>
                    <div class="slds-checkbox" style="float:left;padding-bottom:10px;padding-top:10px;"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="CheckUnCheckAll" value="Check" checked="" /> 
                                <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="CheckUnCheckAll"> 
                                  <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                  <span class="slds-form-element__label">Check/ UnCheck All</span> 
                                </label> 
                    </div> 
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Incentive</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                      <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Annual Price Increase" value="Annual Price Increase" checked="" /> 
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Annual Price Increase"> 
                                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Annual Price Increase</span> 
                                            </label> 
                                      </div> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                  <option>%</option>
                                                  <option>$</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                      </div>


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                      <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Fund" value="Fund" checked="" /> 
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Fund"> 
                                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Fund</span> 
                                            </label> 
                                      </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                  <option>%</option>
                                                  <option>$</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                      </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                      <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Multi-Category" value="Multi-Category" checked="" /> 
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Multi-Category"> 
                                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Multi-Category</span> 
                                            </label> 
                                      </div> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                  <option>%</option>
                                                  <option>$</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                      </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                      <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Multi Channel" value="Multi Channel" checked="" /> 
                                        <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Multi Channel"> 
                                          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                          <span class="slds-form-element__label">Multi Channel</span> 
                                        </label> 
                                      </div> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                  <option>%</option>
                                                  <option>$</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                      </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                      <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Total Category" value="Total Category" checked="" /> 
                                        <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Total Category"> 
                                          <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                          <span class="slds-form-element__label">Total Category</span> 
                                        </label> 
                                      </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                        <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                  <option>%</option>
                                                  <option>$</option>
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                      </div>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                          <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Value Add" value="Value Add" checked="" /> 
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Value Add"> 
                                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Value Add</span> 
                                            </label> 
                                          </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                    <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                      <option>%</option>
                                                      <option>$</option>
                                                    </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                            <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                          </div>

                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                          <div class="slds-checkbox"> 
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="Product Additioanl Incentive" value="Additional Incentive" checked="" /> 
                                            <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="Product Additioanl Incentive"> 
                                              <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> 
                                              <span class="slds-form-element__label">Additional Incentive</span> 
                                            </label> 
                                          </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            <div class="slds-select_container" style="float:right">
                                                    <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                                                      <option>%</option>
                                                      <option>$</option>
                                                    </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                            <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                          </div>

                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>

                    <div class="slds-border_bottom" style="padding:5px;"></div>
                    <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <div style="display:block">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" style="float:left; font-weight:bold;">Overall Incentives % </div>

                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                    <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                  </div>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-size--3-of-12" style="float:right;">
                                        <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1"  required="" class="slds-input" />
                                      </div>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                        <div style="float:right;padding:5px;">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                        <div style="float:right;padding:5px;">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Apply</button>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>        
                </div>
```